# angular-tags: Reset the tags input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

`index.html`

```
<div class="modal-header" >
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click = "submit(information.add, information.subject, information.emailContent); close()">×</button>
                <h3>Compose Email</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name = "form.email">
                    <tags options="{addable: true}" typeahead-options="typeaheadOpts" data-model="information.add" data-src="toPerson as toPerson for toPerson in to"></tags>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;" data-ng-model = "information.subject"><br />
                    <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10" data-ng-model = "information.emailContent"></textarea>
                </form>
            </div>
```

`emailViewController.js`

```
 $scope.information = {
              add: [],
              subject: [],
              emailContent: []
            };

 $scope.clear = function() {
                if ($scope.information.add !== "") {
                  $scope.information = null;
              }  
            };
```

I am setting the value of `$scope.information` to `null`. After doing this, the `input` box value bound to `information.subject` and the `textarea` value bound to `information.emailContent` are reset. However, the `tags input` value bound to `information.add` does not reset. Does anyone know why this is being caused.

I think `$scope.remove()` in the `angular-tags` widget should be used to remove the tag. I am not sure how to implement it though. `Angular-tags` source code can be found here - https://github.com/boneskull/angular-tags/blob/master/src/tags.js

Here is a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/PaG1k5N37BTOflObnN7K?p=preview

**Attempt 1**

This is a plunker of what I have tried so far - http://plnkr.co/edit/jjE2bU8zkkyw36rtAymL?p=preview . I am redefining the value of `$scope.info` to `null` in a function wrapped inside `$timeout`. I thought maybe the changes I made to the `$scope` are not being applied to the view, so I tried to wrap it in a `$timeout`. Doing so did not fix the problem though.

Comment: Please make a fiddle to demonstrate the issue and I'll take a look, cheers.

Comment: @Hal9K I have updated my question with a plunker. In the plunker, even when I redefine the value of `$scope.info.select` to `null`, the `tags` input does not change. I want its value to be reset. For example, if I enter `Marie` and `John` (elements in `$scope.to`) in the `tags` input, I want the `tags` input to be empty when `Remove all values` is clicked.

Comment: @Hal9K Here is a plunker of what I have tried so far - http://plnkr.co/edit/elPefHusJMunHEOhP0HI?p=preview . Please look at the "Attempt 1" section of my question also.

Comment: I got it to delete all and I dont see any value on the input... Does this address your problem? And then I can explain what the issue was...http://plnkr.co/edit/QGL9uxkLUUX8RlKmOg47?p=preview

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code `$scope.information = null;` is supposed to nuke all your information and clear the entire thing? This only sets the reference to the object containing the arrays to null. The arrays are still there and still referenced by your widget I expect - (I'm not sure how the library you are using for your tags is implemented)

The below code actually empties the arrays:

`$scope.information.add.length = 0;
$scope.information.subject.length = 0;
$scope.information.emailContent.length = 0;`

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. It works for `$scope.information.add.length = 0`, but for `$scope.information.subject.length = 0` it gives an error that says, `Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of Hi`

Comment: In your plunker, when I type "j", `John` appears as a suggestion. After that when I click on `Remove items`, it is reset. This functionality is perfect. However, when i enter "j" again, "John" does not appear as a suggestion anymore. I want "John" to keep appearing as a suggestion.

Comment: I was deleting $scope.to in delete() so your list wasn't there to check against the second time. I just removed that line and it works as expected.

Comment: I figured out why `Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of Hi` is occurring. It is because I am using `use strict` mode. The error did not occur as soon as I removed `use strict`. However, it still does not reset the value of `$scope.information.subject` to `0`

Comment: If you want to set the length of a string to 0 do `$scope.information.subject = '';`

Comment: No. This is the `$scope.information` object - `$scope.information = {
              add: [],
              subject: [],
              emailContent: []
            };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88329/discussion-between-hal-9k-and-michelle).